# How to STOP the ASP.NET Identity API from creating a DbContext on every request when using services.AddDefaultIdentity()?

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I am using the ASP.NET Identity API in ASP.NET 8, using the following code in `Program.cs`:

```
var services = builder.Services;
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
}).AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();
```

With this code, ASP.NET creates an instance of `MyDbContext` **on EVERY request**, regardless of whether the `MyDbContext` was dependency injected into the controller.

My problem is, I do **NOT** want a database connection created for some of the endpoints in my application. How do I **stop** ASP.NET 8 from spinning up the Identity API (thus saving a database connection) for some endpoints?

I've tried reading the Microsoft Identity API docs and have not discovered any options yet that would let me accomplish what I'm trying to do.

I have verified that ASP.NET is creating a database connection for every request by logging the connections.

Comment: JFYI database connection are pooled, usually it should not be actually created. My guess would be that marking endpoints with `[AllowAnonymous]` can do the trick. Though doubt that would be a valid workaround for you.

Comment: @GuruStron Unfortunately, adding the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to the endpoints made no difference. It appears that the Identity API is activated upon all controller instantiations in the application, regardless of attributes decorating them (at least the ones I've tried).

Comment: Are there any actual queries made? Don't have setup to repro ATM.